# I'm thinking * buying a house

Tags: prepositions

I want to buy a house. so I'm thinking now what and how can I buy ...

What is the correct preposition with "I'm thinking * buying"?  I use Google books and I found the following:

> I love my place in France and I'm thinking **on** buying one in Florida ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=m-TD1RFp7d4C&pg=PA386&dq=%22I%27m%20thinking%20on%20buying%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ2p6t3cfSAhXBPRoKHU3mBFwQ6AEIHjAB#v=onepage&q=%22I'm%20thinking%20on%20buying%22&f=false)

> I'm thinking **about** buying a place in Manhattan ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=QY9_CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT14&dq=%22I%27m%20thinking%20about%20buying%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwsoa_8sfSAhWODBoKHVN8CdAQ6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=%22I'm%20thinking%20about%20buying%22&f=false)

> I'm thinking **of** buying a tie and can't decide which of these two. [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=xBFeDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT99&dq=%22I%27m%20thinking%20of%20buying%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBjP7h9sfSAhWGtxQKHcMdBoYQ6AEISDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22I'm%20thinking%20of%20buying%22&f=false)

In my following dialog, which one should I use? if all of them are correct, which one is commonly used?

I want to ask my friend to advise:

> I'm thinking **of / about / on** buying a house, you bought one before ... what do you advise?

Comment: "Of" and "about" are most common. "On" has a slightly different meaning and sounds more colloquial.

Comment: **On** is definitely uncommon I'd consider using it only in: *I'm thinking on a new project; I'm thinking on a new book.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Of** and **about** are by far the most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m%20thinking%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2CI%20%27m%20thinking%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20there%3B%2Cc0), and mean essentially the same thing.

[In fact, when we look specifically for "I'm thinking * buying", any other choice is so rare it might as well not exist.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m%20thinking%20*%20buying&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2CI%20%27m%20thinking%20%2A%20buying%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20of%20buying%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BI%20%27m%20thinking%20about%20buying%3B%2Cc0)  The author you quote as writing "I'm thinking *on* buying..." might be using a regionalism.

Comment: I might be wrong but I remember reading that "of" goes mostly with living things while "about" goes with object. So it's: I'm thinking about buying a house. And I'm thinking of buying her a present.

Comment: @SovereignSun: bear in mind that what you are thinking about, in both cases, is an abstract concept: the idea of buying something. Regardless of what you want to buy, the "buying something" is still an abstract concept.

Comment: @SovereignSun: if you compare thinking about X vs thinking of X (no buying involved), then about is more common than of for both dogs and houses. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thinking+of+houses%2Cthinking+about+houses%2Cthinking+of+dogs%2Cthinking+about+dogs&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthinking%20of%20houses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthinking%20about%20houses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthinking%20of%20dogs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthinking%20about%20dogs%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @SovereignSun: Good observation, although I'm not sure it's 100% accurate - consider, for example, [the phrase "I'm thinking of a number..."](https://www.google.com/search?q=i'm+thinking+of+a+number+between+1+and+100)

Comment: @stangdon Maybe, just maybe, **of** also conveys the meaning of *"just now; at this moment"*? While about conveys *"often, sometimes; not exactly now, but maybe now too"*?

Answer (score -2):

Another alternative: *I'm thinking to buy a house.*

*Of* rather means that you have a plan that you constantly remind yourself of, whereas *about* means your thoughts still circle over / about the the general problem space. *On* I never heard.